# How to re-render in react after x-time (Mutation Apollo)

Tags: javascript, graphql, shopify, apollo

I am sending a bulk data request to Shopify graphql to get all the products in the store, which may take a while depending on how many products the store has, so instead of using useQuery, Shopify recommends to send a bulk request using useMutation more on that [here](https://shopify.dev/tutorials/perform-bulk-operations-with-admin-api) , anyway here is my code.

```
const BULK_INIT_MUTATION = gql`
    mutation {
        bulkOperationRunQuery(
            query: """
            {
              products {
                edges {
                  node {
                    id
                    images{
                      edges{
                        node{
                          id
                          originalSrc
                          altText
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
            """
        ) {
            bulkOperation {
                id
                status
            }
            userErrors {
                field
                message
            }
        }
    }
`;


const Index = () => {
    const [createBulkRequest, { data }] = useMutation(BULK_INIT_MUTATION);
    createBulkRequest();

    return <Page>Hi Index</Page>;
};
```

Above should initiate a bulk request to shopify and as per Shopify docs it will take them anything between couple seconds to couples minutes to have the data ready for me to fetch using `useQuery`  with below query

```
query {
  currentBulkOperation {
    id
    status
    errorCode
    createdAt
    completedAt
    objectCount
    fileSize
    url
    partialDataUrl
  }
}
```

When everything is all good above query will return something like this

```
{
  "data": {
    "currentBulkOperation": {
      "id": "gid:\/\/shopify\/BulkOperation\/720918",
      "status": "COMPLETED",
      "errorCode": null,
      "createdAt": "2019-08-29T17:16:35Z",
      "completedAt": "2019-08-29T17:23:25Z",
      "objectCount": "57",
      "fileSize": "358",
      "url": "https:\/\/storage.googleapis.com\/shopify\/dyfkl3g72empyyoenvmtidlm9o4g?<params>",
      "partialDataUrl": null
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

now all I am interested at is the `url` value, which should link to an address where I can get the actual data.

**Now the issue is** unless the Shopify Server had all the time it needed to process my request, it will always return the `url` value as undefined, what I need is a way to maybe constantly request the data after x time until it finally returns the url hence the operation status's completed and then re-render.

I am not sure what's the best way to approach this is, I am thinking something like setInterval, but I'm really not sure. so any suggestion would be quite helpful as I've been stuck with this for couple days now?

I have already tried useEffect like below

```
const Index = () => {
    const [response, setData] = useState({});

    const [createBulkRequest, { data }] = useMutation(BULK_INIT_MUTATION);
    createBulkRequest();

    useEffect(() => {
        const timer = setInterval(() => {
            const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(BULK_STATUS_QUERY);
            console.log('returned data', data);
            setData(data);
        }, 5000);
        // clearing interval
        return () => clearInterval(timer);
    });

    return <Page>Hi Index</Page>;
};
```

However doing this throws this error.

> Unhandled Runtime Error Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be
> called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen
> for one of the following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug
>    and fix this problem.

Comment: useQuery can have `interval` and `skip` values - use them ... onCompleted check value and block next intervals using skip

Comment: Can u write a detailed response with like sample code example as I am not sure what skip values mean and also how to utilize the onCompleted check... etc.

Comment: `skip` blocks execution, `onCompleted` gets data, can be used to stop next executions by changing variable used in `skip` option

Answer (score 0):

If you need to schedule some task after `x` amount of time in order to retrieve data and update some state if defined, then you can use the `setInterval()` method calls a function in a `useEffect` hook (make sure to clear your interval in the return of that useEffect)

Comment: when I do that I get  this error 

Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

Comment: Please have a look at my updated code for info on how I've implemented the useEffect.